# PHP Register Form bringing error

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a regfister system which will send users an activation code once they register, however I am getting errors with the register form which states"syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO in register.php on line 133.

```html
<?php
include('database_connection.php');
?>
<head>
  <title>HireMyItems</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icons/logo.png" />`
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
   <div id="banner">
     <h1>HireMyItems</h1>
        <div id="menubar">
          <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
   <li><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">ContactUs</a></li>
            <li><a href="basket.html">Basket</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--close menubar-->
     <div id="contact">
       <a href="https://twitter.com/HireItems" target="_blank""><img src="images/icons/twitter.png" /></a>
    <a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/people/HireMy-Items/100009321336405"target="_blank""><img src="images/icons/facebook.png"  /></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/preview?locale=en_US&trk=prof-0-sb-preview-primary-button"target="_blank"><img src="images/icons/linkedin.png" /></a>
     </div><!--close welcome-->
   </div><!--close banner-->
    </div><!--close header-->

 <div id="site_content"> 
   <div class="sidebar_container">       
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h2>Rent Items</h2>
   
            <p>Please contact us by email or telephone if you want to list an item for renting.</p>
      <div class="button_small">
        <a href="#">ContactUs</a>
      </div><!--close button_small-->
          </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->       
  <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_item">
            <h2>GreenRecycle</h2>
   <a href="http://www.greenrecycling.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img src="images/banners/greenrecycle.png"></a>
            <p></p>
     <div class="">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div><!--close button_small-->
          </div><!--close sidebar_item--> 
        </div><!--close sidebar-->  
       </div><!--close sidebar_container--> 
    

<h6>Register Form</h6>           
<form action="Register.php" method="post">

<p>Create A new Account <span style="background:#EAEAEA none repeat scroll 0 0;line-height:1;margin-left:210px;;padding:5px 7px;"> Already a member? <a href="login.php">Log in</a></span> </p> 

<div id="registermain">
<div id="register">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Email :</label>
<input id="name" name="email" placeholder="email" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Register ">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) { 

 $error = array(); //Declare An Array to store any error message 

  if (empty($_POST['name'])) { //if no name has been supplied 

  $error[] = 'Please Enter a UserName '; //add to array "error" 

 } else { 

$name = $_POST['name']; //else assign it a variable 

 } 

if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) { 


$error[] = 'Please Enter your Email '; 

 } else { 

 if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", 


  $_POST['e-mail'])) { 

 //regular expression for email validation 

   $Email = $_POST['e-mail']; 

 } else { 

  $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  '; 
 } 
  } 
  
  if (empty($_POST['Password'])) { 
 $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password '; 
 
    } else { 

$Password = $_POST['Password']; 

} 

if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error ' 

{ // If everything's OK... 

// Make sure the email address is available:
 $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM login  WHERE email ='$Email'";
  $result_verify_email = mysql_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
 if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if
 ($result_verify_email==false)
  echo ' Database Error Occured ';
  }
  
  if (mysql_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { //IF no previous user is using this email .  
  // Create a unique  activation code:
  $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
  
  $query_insert_user =   "INSERT INTO `members` ( `username`, `email`, `password`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password', '$activation')";
  
  
 $result_insert_user = mysql_query($dbc, $query_insert_user); 

if (!$result_insert_user) { 
echo 'Query Failed '; 
   } 
   if (mysql_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successful.
   
   
 // Send the email: 

$message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n"; 

$message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation"; 

 mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From:'.EMAIL); 

// Flush the buffered output. 

// Finish the page: 

echo '<div class="success">Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been sent to ' . $Email . 

 ' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>'; 
 } else { // If it did not run OK.
 
echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</div>'; 
   } 

   
 } else { // The email address is not available. 


echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email address has already been registered. </div>'; 
   } 
   
   } else { //If the "error" array contains error msg , display them
   
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
 foreach ($error as $key => $values) {
  echo '  <li>' . $values . '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ol></div>';
  }
  
  mysql_close($dbc); //Close the DB Connection
  } // End of the main Submit conditional.
  ?>
```

Database_connection.php file

```html
<?php

/*define the database connection
DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'XXXX');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'XXXX');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'login');


//This is the address that will appear coming from ( Sender ) 
define('EMAIL', 'ZZZZ@gmail.com'); 


/*Define the root url where the script will be found such as */ 
DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://zzz.com'); 


// Establishing Connection with Server and making the connection
$dbc = mysql_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);

if (!$dbc) { 
trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_connect_error()); 
} 
?>
```

Register.php, where i am getting an error.

```html
$query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email ='$Email'";
  $result_verify_email = mysql_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
 if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if
 $result_verify_email==false;
  echo ' Database Error Occured ';
  }
  
  if (mysql_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { //IF no previous user is using this email .  
  // Create a unique  activation code:
  $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
  
  $query_insert_user =   "INSERT INTO `members` ( `username`, `email`, `password`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password', '$activation')";
  
  
 $result_insert_user = mysql_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
```

Comment: By the way, you're not doing any input sanitation, meaning you're open to all sorts of SQL Injection or XSS attacks. In this case it means the attacker can freely manipulate your database by injecting SQL into your INSERT statement.

Comment: Which line is line 133? Please post the content of that line so we don't have to count to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` condition

```
if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if
 ($result_verify_email==false)
  echo ' Database Error Occured ';
  }
```

This line `($result_verify_email==false)` should be

```
$result_verify_email==false;
```

**Update :**

Uncomment your credentials in your `database_connection.php` file

```
DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'XXXX');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'XXXX');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'login');
```

or

```
DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'XXXX');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'XXXX');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'login');
```

or

change your `$dbc` accordingly

```
$dbc = mysql_connect(XXXX, XXXX, localhost, login);
```

And change this line to this because it tries to fetch data even if there is no data

```
 if (!$result_verify_email) { 
 $result_verify_email==false;
  echo ' Database Error Occured ';
  exit();
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74840/discussion-on-answer-by-sulthan-allaudeen-php-register-form-bringing-error).